# Using CSS "padding-trick" for proportional resizing on Y-axis?

Tags: html, css

I'm building an web app which has a 100% height/width/fullscreen layout. I am looking for a CSS-trick to proportionally resize an elements dimensions according to its height.

Right now I am looking for an equivalent of what this trick does to the x-axis:

```css
html, body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
#view {
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#test-hld {
  position: absolute;
 display: flex; 
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: tomato;
 width: 100%;
 height: 75%;
}

.test{
 position: relative;
 width: 30%;  
}

.test:before{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 75%;
}

.content{
 position:  absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="view">
 <div id="test-hld">
  <div class="test">
   <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But changing (for example) `.test{height: 80%}` and `.test:before{padding-left: 75%}` makes the browser render no dimensions of the box at all.

**My question(s) is**
Why is the opposite not working? 
Has it something fundamental to do with setting heights of elements with CSS?
Can flex/flexbox solve this?

*I know it's possible to fix this with some lines of JS but I just can't believe it's not doable with CSS until someone slaps my face telling me to get real.*

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. I can't seem to break your layout by changing the height and padding-left. Here is a JSFiddle of your original code. Can you update it so that it breaks? http://jsfiddle.net/pazp3k3x/

Comment: I guess my example there was misleading. What I meant was that it's possible to use this CSS-trick to change the size of the box proportionally according to it's width. But when I try to do the ”same” thing, using it's height property, it fails. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/pazp3k3x/1/ (look at the .test class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, just to know why the padding trick works.

Padding-top and padding-bottom are **vertical** dimensions that are related to the width (so, an **horizontal** dimension) of the container.

That allows the ratio of an element to be fixed, and related to the width of the container. But there isn't any horizontal dimension that is related to some vertical of the container, so the equivalent trick over the height is not posible right now.

I have tried to get this same result using another technique, but I have had a very partial success.

My failed attempt is try to use an image to set the ratio

```css
body, html {
  height: 99%;
}

.base {
  height: 40%;
  border: solid 1px green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/400x200");
  opacity: 0.05;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<img class="ratio" />
</div>
```

This is working in IE and Chrome, and failing in FF. But just on initial loading.

Changing the browser size won't work until the page is reloaded. I just can't figure out why, or how to solve it

Comment: Good explanation! I guess I have to solve this by using JS after all, still it's a little bit chocking to me why there's no built in support for this type of resizing in CSS.